# inspect element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, element

i want to get id(or class) of element when i clicked on that.
i write this codes.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').click(function() {
      var idName = $(this).attr('class');
      alert(idName);
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">
    <div class="test2">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but it give me class(id) of parent class.(and undefined)
how i can delete that?(give me just class(or id) of one element)

Answer (score 1):

Add `event.stopPropagation` and use `event.target`:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      var idName = $(e.target).attr('class');
      alert(idName);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr('class')` for class(es), and `.attr('id')` for the id. I updated your example below.

When you click on an element, the click will propogate down through all containing elements and will trigger the click function for each one. To stop propagation use `.stopPropagation()`.

```js
  $().ready(function() {
    $('*').click(function(e) {
      var classNames = $(this).attr('class');
      var idName = $(this).attr('id');
      alert('ID: ' + idName + '\r\nClasses: ' + classNames);
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });
```

```css
#a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px;
}
#a div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.test {
  background-color: green;
}
.test1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.test2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.class1 {
  text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a" class="test">test
  <div id="b" class="test1 class1">test1
    <div id="c" class="test2 class1">
      test2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: stack snippet has different sections for html, css, and js. Why did you put them all in the html section?

Answer (score 1):

Or make it just show ids for each element:

```js
$('*').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var ident = $(event.target).attr('id');
  alert("id = " + ident);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">button</button>
<br>
<br>
<input type="textbox" id="textbox" placeholder="textbox" />
<br>
<br>
<span id="text">text</span>
```